# failed to build lodash project

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have cloned [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) and tried to build the project (`npm run build`) but got this error:

[image]

found these hints on the internet:

- delete `node_modules`
- `npm clean cache`
- `npm i`

None of them worked for me. Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md), "The master branch is in flux while we work on Lodash v5. This means things like npm scripts, which we encourage using for contributions, may not be working. Thank you for your patience".

So it's normal that you got this problem. There is a discussion [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3140) in which is reported your same error.